# See changes made in a project

Tags: git

I have made changes to a project. I now have a modified copy as well as the original copy. I would like to see what changes have been made in the modified project. How do I achieve that?  Thank you.

Comment: Could you please expand on what you've done in git so we have a better understanding where you currently stand

Comment: Are you using a git client of some kind? Or just git command line?

Comment: How about ` git diff` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git diff` shows all changes except deleted (and new) files.

To check ALL changes compared to the last commit (no matter what client) is:

```
# Add all changed including deleted files
git add -A . 
# Show all staged changes
git diff --staged
```

Now just reset the changes that you do no need to commit , or if all is well, commit!

If you want to compare against another branch or refspec after committing: `git diff another_branch_or_refspec HEAD`

Comment: Thanks very much. This worked well :). I didn't run the git add -A command to stage the files and also didn't commit. That's why I was experiencing the problems. Thanks once again.